# How to keep update and store value for a variable in ForEach Loop Table? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let numbers: [Double] = [
        10.0, 50.0, 150.0, 80.0, 30.0, 120.0, 70.0, 20.0, 180.0, 40.0,
        100.0, 60.0, 90.0, 130.0, 170.0, 110.0, 160.0, 140.0, 190.0, 200.0,
        170.0, 30.0, 50.0, 90.0, 120.0, 10.0, 180.0, 70.0, 150.0, 20.0,
        40.0, 110.0, 80.0, 60.0, 140.0, 100.0, 200.0, 130.0, 190.0, 160.0,
        30.0, 150.0, 80.0, 40.0, 120.0, 70.0, 180.0, 110.0, 50.0, 20.0
    ]
    
    let numberOfColumns = 6
    
    // Declare a state variable to store the current column
    @State var currentColumn = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List(numbers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            TableRowView(number: numbers[index], column: columnToShowNumber(numbers[index]))
        }
    }
    
    func columnToShowNumber(_ number: Double) -> Int? {
         //var currentColumn: Int = 0
            var lastUpwardTrend: Double? = nil
        if self.currentColumn == 0 {
                    //reset_all()
            self.currentColumn = 2
                    lastUpwardTrend = number
            print("currentColumn starts at Upward Trend column successfully:", self.currentColumn,", lastUpwardTrend:", lastUpwardTrend! )
                    return 2
                }
        if self.currentColumn == 2 && lastUpwardTrend != number {
                    if  number > lastUpwardTrend! {
                        lastUpwardTrend = number
                        return 2
                    }
                }

        
        return nil
    }
}

struct TableRowView: View {
    let number: Double
    let column: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<6) { columnIndex in
                if columnIndex == column {
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .border(Color.gray)
                } else {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

In this example code, the variable currentColumn resets to 0 on every new row, that makes the currentColumn cannot remain the updated value on the last row and enter the if conditions correctly on the new row. How to make variable currentColumn to store the updated value on the last row and maintain the updated value in the new row?

Comment: I have really no idea what you are trying to do but I guess currentColumn should be passed to TableRowView as a Binding and updated there, the whole functionality of columnToShowNumber needs to be handled in TableRowView and I also see that your condition `lastUpwardTrend != number` is pointless since lastUpwardTrend is a local variable and will always be nil when this condition is checked.

Comment: My design is that: one number for one row, there are 6 columns on one row. each row will show one number or leave it blank; which column shows the number on that row, determined by some rules. The first row always record the numer on the 3rd column, the following column will check if value is larger than the last number on 3rd column, then record it on 3rd column; if not, leave it blank, and do the same for the rest rows

Comment: currentColumn representing the current column the number is recording, because the actual project has six columns to be switching between, and it is a bit different from the use of columnIndex == 1, so I create this variable; lastUpwardTrend represents the last number recording on the 3rd column, and here in this example code, it is the last highest number recorded on 3rd column, and I compare it with the new number and see whether the new number should be shown on 3rd column or not

Comment: Ok but I still don’t understand your code since there are no columns of any kind in it but maybe that’s because it’s been simplified. Anyway I still think the points I made in my first comment are valid.

Comment: Still cannot get the right result.. could you please show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is that it doesn't work that way. What you need to bear in mind:

- You cannot assume that the `ForEach` is executed exactly once, nor that the views inside the `ForEach` are created exactly once. For example, when the `List` is scrolled, rows may be discarded and later re-created.
- A `View` is supposed to be exactly that, a ***view*** of a data model, not the model itself. This also means, it should be possible to create and also re-create the view for any row in isolation from the other rows, based purely on its id.

So one way to solve the problem is to move the processing that you're trying to perform in `columnToShowNumber` to a class that can deliver the results to the view. You probably want to perform the processing once, when the parent view is first created. Then the rows provide a view of this data.

In the updated version below, the processing has been moved to a new class called `TrendAnalysis`. If the analysis is not working correctly then it can be fixed by correcting the function `populateIndices`. For simplicity, I have changed the optional `Int` (for the index positions) to a plain `Int` and used -1 for non-matching positions.

```swift
class TrendAnalysis {
    var columnIndices: [Int]

    init(numbers: [Double]) {
        columnIndices = [Int]()
        populateIndices(numbers: numbers)
    }

    private func populateIndices(numbers: [Double]) {
        columnIndices.reserveCapacity(numbers.count)
        var currentColumn = 0
        var lastUpwardTrend: Double? = nil
        for number in numbers {
            let index: Int
            if currentColumn == 0 {
                currentColumn = 2
                lastUpwardTrend = number
                print("currentColumn starts at Upward Trend column successfully:", currentColumn,", lastUpwardTrend:", lastUpwardTrend! )
                index = 2
            } else if currentColumn == 2 && number > (lastUpwardTrend ?? -1) {
                index = 2
                lastUpwardTrend = number
            } else {
                index = -1
            }
            columnIndices.append(index)
        }
    }

    /// - Returns The index of the column in the specified row in which a
    /// number should be shown (0-based), or -1 if none
    func columnForRow(rowIndex: Int) -> Int {
        rowIndex < columnIndices.count ? columnIndices[rowIndex] : -1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let numbers = [
        10.0, 50.0, 150.0, 80.0, 30.0, 120.0, 70.0, 20.0, 180.0, 40.0,
        100.0, 60.0, 90.0, 130.0, 170.0, 110.0, 160.0, 140.0, 190.0, 200.0,
        170.0, 30.0, 50.0, 90.0, 120.0, 10.0, 180.0, 70.0, 150.0, 20.0,
        40.0, 110.0, 80.0, 60.0, 140.0, 100.0, 200.0, 130.0, 190.0, 160.0,
        30.0, 150.0, 80.0, 40.0, 120.0, 70.0, 180.0, 110.0, 50.0, 20.0
    ]
    let analysis: TrendAnalysis
    let numberOfColumns = 6

    init() {
        self.analysis = TrendAnalysis(numbers: numbers)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(Array(numbers.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, number in
            TableRowView(
                number: number,
                column: analysis.columnForRow(rowIndex: index)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct TableRowView: View {
    let number: Double
    let column: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<6) { columnIndex in
                if column == columnIndex {
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .border(Color.gray)
                } else {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried to improve the way the values are presented, currently it shows the following:

[image: TrendValues]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! That’s exactly the result I wanted! You and the other user are both correct, but you provided a much more detailed answer! Thank you so much!