# How to increment an integer in a ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I have a fairly simple grid layout:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var gridSize = 3
    @State var selected = 0
    @State var aCount = 0

    var body: some View {

        Grid (horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<gridSize, id: \.self) { row in
                GridRow{
                    ForEach(0..<gridSize, id: \.self) { col in
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .overlay(Text("\(aCount)"))
                            .border(Color.black)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This creates a grid of gridSize x gridsize grey rectangles, so 3x3 in this version

and in a class file I have a fairly simple function that increments an int passed to it by 1 and returns that new value:

```
func theIncrement(theCount: Int) -> Int {
    let theCounter = theCount + 1
    return theCounter
}
```

how do I use that function to increment aCount in the inner foreach loop? This does not seem like it should be impossible, and yet...

any help is appreciated

Comment: What `aCount` should be in `Text("\(aCount)")` can be calculated from `row` and `col`. You should do that instead. If you can't do that because your real code is different, please show your real code.

Comment: See the answer to [How to keep update and store value for a variable in ForEach Loop Table? SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77119651/20386264).

Comment: @Sweeper did you delete one of your answers? I didn't have time to look at it yesterday, but it looked really helpful at a glance and now i can't see it.

Answer (score -1):

In SwiftUI, views are supposed to be a function of state – they are driven by external state. Each view's `body` property can be executed multiple times to determine if the view has changed and needs redrawing.

For that reason, changing external state while looping through a `ForEach` is a very bad idea, and is

If you need to express a relationship between the controls you're looping through, it is best to find a way to express that relationship in your state *before* you get to looping through it.

Comment: Okay, but are there any places that actually have examples of this? If I could figure out how to do this, I wouldn't need to ask for help.